# Batch File Concatenation With Special Character

Tags: batch-file, special-characters, concatenation, dos

I need to create a string variable in my DOS Batch file to contain the following: "Server1\StoreDB"

My StoreDB is coming from a query to the database so currently, my script looks like this:

```
set Instance=%1
set path1="Server1\"
set "CompletePath=%path1%%Instance%"
```

But this doesn't return "Server1\StoreDB". It only returns "StoreDB"

A little help here please? I am new to these DOS commands. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have problems/potential problems with quotes.
Use %~1 instead of %1 to remove potential quotes.
The placement of quotes in your second line is incorrect.

```
set Instance=%~1
set "path1=Server1\"
```

Comment: You have identified and fixed problems with the OP's code, but I don't think it is the root of the problem being described

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you have paraphrased your code, and some of the lines you show are actually part of a larger construct that is within parentheses or concatenated commands.

`%var%` is expanded when the line is parsed, and a parenthesized block of code is parsed all at once. If a variable is set and expanded within the same block of code, then the expanded value is the value that existed before the block of code was parsed.

The solution is to use delayed expansion `!var!`, which must be enabled using `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "var=original"
(
  set "var=new"
  echo %%var%% in block = %var%
  echo ^^!var^^! in block = !var!
)
echo %%var%% after block = %var%
echo ^^!var^^! after block = !var!
```

--OUTPUT--

```
%var% in block = original
!var! in block = new
%var% after block = new
!var! after block = new
```